# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "channels" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku and I was getting the sqlite3 error so I followed the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
to switch to postgres but now I'm getting an error when I run rails db:migrate.

I've already tried dropping the database and creating it again with rails db:drop db:create, but haven't been able to get it to work.

My migration:

```rb
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :session_id
      t.references :channel, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my room model:

```rb
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :channel
  has_many :users
end
```

In my Channel model:

```rb
class Channel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :registrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :registrations
end
```

I get this error when running rails db:migrate

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "channels" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "rooms" ("id" bigserial primary key, "name" character varying, "description" text, "session_id" integer, "channel_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_1f9c11d4ad"
FOREIGN KEY ("channel_id")
  REFERENCES "channels" ("id")
)
/CIS-196/final-project/db/migrate/20201128050333_create_rooms.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "channels" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "rooms" ("id" bigserial primary key, "name" character varying, "description" text, "session_id" integer, "channel_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_1f9c11d4ad"
FOREIGN KEY ("channel_id")
  REFERENCES "channels" ("id")
)
/CIS-196/final-project/db/migrate/20201128050333_create_rooms.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "channels" does not exist
/CIS-196/final-project/db/migrate/20201128050333_create_rooms.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

This is the schema:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_12_12_224511) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "channels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "registrations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "channel_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["channel_id"], name: "index_registrations_on_channel_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_registrations_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "channel_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "session_id"
    t.index ["channel_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_channel_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "password_hash"
    t.text "bio"
    t.integer "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_users_on_room_id"
  end

end
```

These are the migration files:
[screenshot of migration files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiJYI.jpg)

Comment: I guess you need to create the channels table before you create the rooms table. Can you list the file names that are in your db/migrate folder?

Comment: The files are: 20201128050215_create_users; 20201128050333_create_rooms; 20201128050352_create_channels; 20201128050445_create_registrations; 20201128062322_add_devise_to_users; 20201212090248_add_session_to_rooms; 20201212224511_create_active_storage_tables.active_storage

Answer (score 1):

Your rooms table references the channel table. Therefore you need to create the channel table before you create the rooms table. You need to rename the migration which creates the channels table so that it appears before the migration that creates the rooms table.

Thus rename `20201128050352_create_channels.rb` to `20201128050332_create_channels.rb` so it will run before `20201128050333_create_rooms.rb`. Then run `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`.